# Text Compression when serving from a Github Trigger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gzip

I'm trying to figure out how to serve my js, css and html as compressed gzip from my Google Cloud Storage bucket. I've set up my static site properly, and also built a Cloud Build Trigger to sync the contents from the repository on push. My problem is that I don't want to have gzips of these files on my repository, but rather just serve them from the bucket.

I might be asking too much for such a simple setup, but perhaps there is a command I can add to my cloudbuild.yaml to make this work.

At the moment it is just this:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args: ["-m", "rsync", "-r", "-c", "-d", ".", "gs://my-site.com"]
```

As far as I'm aware this just syncs the bucket to the repo. Is there another command that could ensure that the aforementioned files are transferred as gzip? I've seen use of the `gsutil cp`
but not within this specific Cloud Build pipeline setup from Github.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gsutil command [setmeta](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta) lets you add metadata information to the files that overwrites the default http server. Which is handy for Content-Type, and Cache-* options.

```
gsutil setmeta -h "Content-Encoding: gzip" gs://bucket_name/folder/*
```

For more info about Transcoding with gzip-uploaded files: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding